# Need a code approach/recommendation [python,django,html]

Tags: python, html, django

I am working with django and python and my goal is to be able to make some type of python function call (without refreshing page) to display different information based on onclick events.

Some generic code below shows my setup. Essentially, when a button inside parent2 is clicked I want to be able to make a function call with that buttons id to some python function. Then I want to basically rerender part of the page to display the results inside parent1.

Im not sure how realistic this is but, would appreciate any help in the right direction.

```
<div id="parent1">
    <div class="child_style">
        {%for i in mydata1%}
            <div> my child 0</div>
            ...
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
<div id = "parent2">
    <div class="other_style">
        {%for j in mydata2%}
            <div><div><div><div><a id="..">Button0</a></div></div></div></div>
            ...
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: search for "ajax and django". Apart from that, this is not a specific question, too broad to answer.

Comment: use jquery. This will allow you to update part of a page without refreshing it. some examples here https://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/jquery.html

Comment: @Jacobr365 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this function to your views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

@api_view(["GET" , "POST"])

def demo(request):

  buttonId=request.GET.get('button-id',None)
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"result":"you have clicked the button"+buttonId}))
```

Here, the `buttonId` will be the mentioned button id...

then,add this in your urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
#import views.py file as view

urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^demo$', view.demo,name='demo'),
]
```

Now, You can call this function using AJAX in your javascript code, thus you get the response which can be updated in`<div id="parent1">` as like,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
        url: '/demo',
        data: JSON.stringify({'button-id':'demo-button'}),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data['result'])
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here, you are passing a JSON object `{'button-id':'demo-button'}` in request where `demo-button` is your button id.
and you get a response as JSON `{"result":"you have clicked the demo-button"}` which you can get the value by calling `data['result']`.

You can replace `console.log(data['result']` with your own functions

Please note: you should change your `<a>` tag... instead you can use a `<button>` with `onClick` event listener..
as like

`<div><div><div><div><button id="some_id" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">Button</button></div></div></div></div>`

where `myFunc()` is...

```
function myFunc(id){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/demo',
    data: JSON.stringify({'button-id':id}),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data['result'])
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This seems to still reload the page. Also not sure the purpose for why we are addiing a new url?

Comment: its because you have initialted `<a>` tag on your button. instead you can use `onClick` in button tag. like...`onClick="myFunc(this.id);"` where `myFunc` will be having your ajax code

Comment: `<div><div><div><div><button id="some_id" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">Button</button></div></div></div></div>`